# Проблема в слушателях одного топика Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Есть топик `TOPIC_1`,  который слушают два слушателя `C_1` and `C_2`, находящиеся в одной группе `group_1`. У обоих из них стоит стратегия `RoundRobinAssignor` , но при подключении второго слушателя выбрасывается ошибка :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentGroupProtocolException: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members or first group member tried to join with empty protocol type or empty protocol list.
```

Так-же есть третий слушатель, но уже находится в другом топике `TOPIC_2`, но у него такая-же группа `group_1`, но другая стратегия. Влияет-ли это как-то? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было поменять группу у третьего слушателя. Либо добавить третьему слушателю аналогичную стратегию, как и у других.